# SQL query cannot be converted to LINQ

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

When I'm trying to convert this  piece of SQL to LINQ, I received this error:

> SQL cannot be converted to LINQ: Table [GL] not found in the current
>   Data Context.

But in SQL it works fine.

This is my SQL query:

```
SELECT  itm.Id ,
        ISNULL(itm.Debit, 0) AS Debit ,
        ISNULL(itm.Credit, 0) AS Credit ,
        itm.State ,
        itm.DocCreateDate ,
        ISNULL(itm.Num, 0) AS Num ,
        ISNULL(itm.DocTypeRef, 0) AS DocTypeRef ,
        itm.Year ,
        itm.Month ,
        ISNULL(itm.DebitCount, 0) AS DebitCount ,
        ISNULL(itm.CreditCount, 0) AS CreditCount ,
        itm.DL ,
        itm.DL2 ,
        itm.DL3 ,
        itm.DL4 ,
        itm.DL5 ,
        itm.DL6 ,
        itm.DL7 ,
        ISNULL(itm.FCRef, 0) AS FCRef ,
        itm.FollowUpNum ,
        ISNULL(itm.BranchRef, 1) AS BranchRef ,
        itm.DocHeaderRef ,
        ISNULL(itm.RowNum, 0) AS RowNum ,
        ISNULL(itm.DailyNum, 0) AS DailyNum ,
        ISNULL(itm.TempNum, 0) AS TempNum ,
        ISNULL(itm.RefNum, 0) AS RefNum ,
        itm.Descript ,
        itm.Count ,
        itm.FollowUpDate ,
        itm.FCVal ,
        itm.FCRateVal ,
        itm.FactorNum ,
        ISNULL(itm.DebitFCVal, 0) AS DebitFCVal ,
        ISNULL(itm.CreditFCVal, 0) AS CreditFCVal ,
        sl.Id AS SLRef ,
        sl.SLCode ,
        sl.Title AS SLTitle ,
        CASE WHEN ISNULL(sl.DLSRef, 0) > 0 THEN 1
             ELSE 0
        END AS HasDL ,
        CASE WHEN ISNULL(sl.DLSRef2, 0) > 0 THEN 1
             ELSE 0
        END AS HasDL2 ,
        CASE WHEN ISNULL(sl.DLSRef3, 0) > 0 THEN 1
             ELSE 0
        END AS HasDL3 ,
        CASE WHEN ISNULL(sl.DLSRef4, 0) > 0 THEN 1
             ELSE 0
        END AS HasDL4 ,
        CASE WHEN ISNULL(sl.DLSRef5, 0) > 0 THEN 1
             ELSE 0
        END AS HasDL5 ,
        CASE WHEN ISNULL(sl.DLSRef6, 0) > 0 THEN 1
             ELSE 0
        END AS HasDL6 ,
        CASE WHEN ISNULL(sl.DLSRef7, 0) > 0 THEN 1
             ELSE 0
        END AS HasDL7 ,
        CASE WHEN ISNULL(sl.HasFC, 0) > 0 THEN 1
             ELSE 0
        END AS HasFC ,
        1 AS HasFollow ,
        tl.Id AS TLRef ,
        tl.Title AS TLTitle ,
        tl.TLCode ,
        gl.Id AS GLRef ,
        gl.Title AS GLTitle ,
        gl.GLCode ,
        gl.Balance AS GLBalance
FROM    Acc.DocItem AS itm
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Acc.SL AS sl ON itm.SLRef = sl.Id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Acc.TL AS tl ON sl.TLRef = tl.Id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Acc.GL AS gl ON tl.GLRef = gl.Id
WHERE   ( itm.SLRef > 0 )
```

If there is no way to pass this error so can you tell me its LINQ equal?

Comment: The error is straight-forward: you don't have the `GL` table in your Data Context - I assume you're using the "Database-First" EDMX approach, in which case your "GL" table does not exist in your EDMX file.

Comment: *why* do people feel this need to take perfectly good, fully working queries that have minimal runtime cost, and feel the need to add LINQ to them, so that everything has to jump through a complex expression generator and query emitter all the time? I just don't get it...

Comment: Can you share your LINQ statement and EDMX designer screenshot?

Comment: Create view and call view.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do that in linq:

```
var q =
    from c in categories
    join p in products on c.Category equals p.Category into ps
    from p in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new { Category = c, ProductName = p == null ? "(No products)" : p.ProductName };
```

This is the big idea for left outer join, **you as the syntax for 'into' like 'as' in SQL query.**